If $f$ is $K$-finite, then $Xf$ is also $K$-finite

This problem comes form bump, Automorphic forms and representations, p,300. It's about the ''K-finiteness'' conditions in the definition of the automorphic forms of $GL(2,A)$, where A is the adele ring of a global field.
For the Archimedean case, we have $G=GL(2,R)$ and $K=O(2)$ or else $G=GL(2,C)$ and $K=U(2)$. In both these cases, it seems that we have the results''If $f$ is $K$-finite, then $Xf$ is defined and also $K$-finite''.
I have no idea to approach this question, is there any hints or comments about this question? Thank you.
